# next-auth / Sign in issue

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next-auth

I am trying to work from this project: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example to see how next-auth works and experiment with it. I hit this issue when trying to log in:

✓ Compiled /api/auth/[...nextauth] in 72ms (598 modules)
⨯ Detected default export in '/Users/me/Documents/Heroku/next-auth-example/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method instead.
⨯ No HTTP methods exported in '/Users/me/Documents/Heroku/next-auth-example/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts'. Export a named export for each HTTP method.

This is /api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts :

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Auth0Provider from "next-auth/providers/auth0"

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Auth0Provider({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH0_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app router, for each http method you must export a handler function with the name of the method. For example:

```
export const GET = () => {
   // code here
}

export const POST = () => {
   // code here
}
```

And if you want use the NextAuth handlers, you must destructure it and export it like this:

```
const { handlers } = NextAuth({ ... })

export const { GET, POST } = handlers
```

in the example you provided, they exported the NextAuth from [here](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example/blob/main/auth.ts) and used it [here](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example/blob/main/app/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D/route.ts)

Comment: @Arash_jahan_bakhshan. When you write in you answer "In the app router", which file (or files) exactly are you referring to ?

Comment: @Michel `/app` which was intruduced in version 13.4 in nextjs. (the old way of creating pages was the `/pages` directory). As i chcked the filenames you provided, you are using app router. so the solution should work for you

Comment: Yes, I guess so, but my question is about precisely which file to touch. In other words, I am not sure where to put the code you suggest.

Comment: @Michel what you have done is almost correct. you just have to restructure the returned object from `NextAuth` as I showed above.

Comment: @Arash_jahan_bakhshan. Indeed that lead me to some  progress, it did not solve it all unfortunately. I created a new post with an updated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77904635/using-next-auth-and-experimenting-the-sign-in-feature.