# Using next-auth and experimenting the Sign in feature

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next-auth

I am trying to work from this project: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example to see how next-auth works and experiment with it. I hit this issue when trying to log in:

After running this:

```
 % npm run dev
```

in the terminal, I point my web browser (Firefox) to the address below:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Then I hit the "Sign In" button; the contents of the address bar changes to:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F
```

Then I hit the "Sign in with Auth0" button; the contents of the address bar changes to:

```
https://dev-g5v8abca6f234b.jp.auth0.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=undefined&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fauth0&code_challenge=heHih6zQrzk4P13PpYGSC6YvHrO7NkXGGlSjsv8BQGQ&code_challenge_method=S256&scope=openid+profile+email
```

And I see in the display:

```
dev-g5v8abca6f234b
Oops!, something went wrong

There could be a misconfiguration in the system or a service outage.
We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us.
Please try again.
TECHNICAL DETAILS
See details for this error
SUPPORT
```

Clicking "See details for this error", I get:

```
invalid_request: Unknown client: undefined
```